# Выход из цикла с unsigned переменной

Tags: c++, циклы

Нужно обработать все значения от `res - 1` до `0` **включительно** (res имеет тип `unsigned long long`)

```
for (size_t i=res-1;i!=UINT_64;--i) {...}
```

Компилируется и работает, но выдаёт предупреждение. Можно ли сделать без предупреждений, не сильно усложняя код (не используя `do...while`)?

Comment: если нужно до 0 включительно, то почему не написать это явно?
`for (size_t j=res+1;j>0;j--) {int i = j-1}` или даже
`for (size_t j=res+1, size_t i = res;j>0;j--, i--) {...}`

Comment: Кстати, `res` у вас какой тип имеет?

Comment: исправил вопрос

Comment: Тогда напишите так `for (unsigned long long i=res-1;i>0;--i)` (+ 1 доп. проверка в цикле)

Comment: @StateItPrimitive будет бесконечный цикл

Comment: @StateItPrimitive `size_t` у меня равен `unsigned long long`

Comment: Вы уверены, что `size_t` у вас это алиас `unsigned long long`, а не `unsigned int`, например?

Comment: @KoVadim я исправил, нужно с `res-1`

Comment: На мой взгляд вариант @KoVadim (только убрать `+1`) больше всего соответствует задаче.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive да, проверил

Comment: @KonstantinLes мы `int` присваиваем `unsigned long long`

Comment: @KonstantinLes так не пойдет, второй случай также

Comment: @andrey777 Не очень понял, где присваиваем?

Comment: @KonstantinLes в решении KoVadim первом

Comment: @andrey777 Понял. Ну заменить `int` на `size_t`. И почему второй вариант не подходит?

Comment: Окей, тогда покажите варнинг, который у вас вылетает.

Comment: Если вы так сильно не хотите использовать тот же `do while`, то можно либо идти от `res до 1 включительно`, либо выражение в `for` вынесите в отдельную процедуру, чтобы не копипастить код, например, вот [так](https://ideone.com/goWQjs).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

```
for (size_t i = res; i--; )
```

http://codepad.org/PXPn5CcK

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(void)
  {
  int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  const int n = sizeof a / sizeof (int);

  for(size_t q = n; q--; )
    printf("%d ", a[q]);

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: а почему бы не написать сравнение с нулём явно? Выглядит же ужасно

Answer (score 1):

Со всей приведенной экзотикой надо и самому извратиться :)...

```
for(size_t i = res-1; i < res; --i)
```

Куда интереснее вопрос, как в цикле прийти ВЕСЬ `unsigned` диапазон... Тут уже `for` не спасет, придется

```
i = 0xFFFFFFFF;
do { ++i; ..... } while (i < 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

Comment: Серьезно? И все же `long long n = 0; for(unsigned i = 0, flag = 1; i || flag; i++, flag = 0)  n++;` выведет n = 4294967296 (т.е. полный диапазон)

Comment: Неспортивно! без лишних переменных. А то так и цикл разбить можно на два :)

Comment: А так? `long long n = 0;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i || !n; i++)
    n++;`

Comment: А что, n и i - это одна переменная?

Comment: Надо просто взять для переменной цикла тип пошире, чем unsigned. Хотя пошире может и не быть. Другой вариант - сделать пару for циклов. Или сделать половинный цикл, а внутри выполнить пару действий.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (size_t i = res-1; i != ~size_t(); --i)
```

http://codepad.org/HejYMgZL

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(void)
  {
  int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  const int n = sizeof a / sizeof (int);

  for(size_t q = n-1; q != ~size_t(); --q)
    printf("%d ", a[q]);

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: бесконечный цикл у меня

Comment: @andrey777, нет, не бесконечный.

Comment: вы, наверное, прочитали вопрос до изменения, res имеет тип `unsigned long long`

Comment: @andrey777, это неважно. Приведи полный минимальный пример, где это условие даёт вечный цикл. Желательно со ссылкой на онлайн-ide.

Comment: @andrey777 Нет, это не бесконечный цикл, правда варнинг никуда не делся :)

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, codepad делает warnings as errors - там нет предупреждения.

Comment: @Qwertiy Хм, ну опять же, на вид это зависит от того, что скрывается за `size_t`, если это алиас для `unsigned int`, а не для `unsigned long long`, то тут в любом случае будет варнинг, который укажет за возможную потерю данных.

Comment: @andrey777, значение, которым инициализируется переменная никак не влияет на способ сравнения.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, где потеря данных в инвертировании всех битов нуля некого беззнакового типа?? Нет там предупреждений.

Comment: @Qwertiy Но ведь это зависит от реализации, `unsigned long long` в принципе может занимать больше байт чем `unsigned int`, и в тоге, если число вылезало за пределы `unsigned int`, но оставалось в `unsigned long long`, то при конвертации из второго в первое явно ображется число, т.к. `sizeof(unsigned long long) - sizeof(unsigned int)` байт отрежутся просто.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, а понял. Ты про первое присваивание, а не про сравнение? Ну так зачем присваивать переменной то, что в неё не влезает?

Comment: @Qwertiy Вот-вот, я про это и говорю, что не пойму, почему бы автору не работать с одним и тем же типом данных (он зачем-то от одного переходит ко второму).

Answer (score 0):

Так делать не надо (потому что часть данных отбросится), но раз уж очень хочется:

```
size_t i = (size_t)(res-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

По крайней мере g++ в 64-bit Ubuntu

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int 
main(int ac, char **av)
{
  unsigned long long res = strtoull(av[1] ? av[1] : "0", 0, 10);

  for (size_t lim = (0UL - 1), i = res - 1; i != lim; i--)
    printf("%lu\n", i);

  return 0;
}
```

Не ругается.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ -Wall c.c
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 3
2
1
0
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Так что, я толком так и не понял, из-за чего весь "сыр-бор".